# Best match search on on object with required and optional fields

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Assume I have a key/value that has the following structure.

```
@Value.Immutable
public interface Key {
  EnumFoo required_enum_one;
  EnumBar required_enum_two;
  Optional<boolean> optional_boolean_one;
  Optional<EnumBaz> optional_enum_two; 
} 

@Value.Immutable
public interface Value {
  Message message; 
}
```

Assume that I have a key/value mapping, where I have a message value for **all** the combinations of the required fields, and **some** combinations of optional fields. For example:

```
{foo1, bar1, true, baz1 } => msg1
{foo1, bar1, true, <any value except baz1> } => msg2
{foo1, bar2, <any value>, <any value> } => msg3
{foo2, bar2, <any value>, <any value> } => msg4
If I do a look up of {foo1, bar2, false, baz1}, it should resolve to msg3
```

What would be the best way to implement this? I was thinking of adding a custom @equals to the key where it skips optional matching when it isnt present in mapping collection. As for the mapping collection, I was thinking of a list of key/value tuples which is ordered based on the presence of the optional fields(similar to above code block), so that the first key which matches **all** required fields and **most** optional fields is selected and the corresponding value is returned?

Is there a better approach? As a bonus, I find myself repeating this pattern for different types. Is there a way to have a reusable solution?

Comment: Your requirement is not complete. Let say you have `{f1, b1, null, b1} -> msg3`, `{f1, b1, null, b2} -> msg4` then which message do you have for {f1, b1, null, b4} when search? Return `msg3` or `msg4`?

Comment: Both **msg3** and **msg4** should not be returned, as there is an optional field present which doesnt match. The valid maps would be ```{f1, b1, null, b4}, {f1, b1, b2, b4}, {f1, b1, null, null}``` in this order.

Comment: I have a possible solution, however, I would like to gain a certain understanding of the restrictions of the problem. 1. Does the order of arguments passed of of the key, i.e. foo, bar etc matter? 2. Must they be enums or would strings suffice? 3. Would it suffice to show actual code, partial code implementation or pseudo code?

Comment: Also, if one passed, {foo1, <any>, <any>, <any>} would this return a list?

Comment: The question is unclear and/or not fully specified. For example, how is `{foo1, bar1, true, <any value except baz1> }` represented using your `Key` type? Likewise for `{foo1, bar2, <any value>, <any value> }`. What is the message type? What are the rules for deciding whether two values match?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem in the past by considering the "key of the map" (a `java.util.Map`) to be a separate concern from the "Key type" (the interface you've defined in your q).

I've done this using a StringListMapKey that looks something like:

```
final class StringListMapKey {
    private List<String> keyParts;

    public StringListMapKey(List<String> keyParts) {
        this.keyParts = keyParts;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof StringListMapKey)) {
            return false;
        }

        return this.keyParts.equals(((StringListMapKey) obj).keyParts);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return keyParts.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can take an instance of the Key type (the one in your question) and transform it to a StringListMapKey using something like this - where you can put in your well-known/static mappings:

```
final class MapKeyFactory {
    private static final String ANY = "$ANY";

    public StringListMapKey createFrom(Key key) {
        List<String> keyParts = new ArrayList<>();

        keyParts.add(key.getEnumFoo()
                        .toString());
        keyParts.add(key.getEnumBar()
                        .toString());

        keyParts.add(deriveMaybeBooleanOneKeyPart(key.isMaybeBooleanOne()));
        keyParts.add(derviceMaybeEnumBazKeyPart(key.getMaybeEnumBaz()));

        return new StringListMapKey(keyParts);
    }

    private String derviceMaybeEnumBazKeyPart(Optional<EnumBaz> maybeEnumBaz) {
        if (!maybeEnumBaz.isPresent()) {
            return ANY;
        }

        EnumBaz enumBaz = maybeEnumBaz.get();

        switch (enumBaz) {
        case BAZ1:
            return "ONE";
        default:
            return ANY;
        }
    }

    private String deriveMaybeBooleanOneKeyPart(Optional<Boolean> maybeBooleanOne) {
        if (!maybeBooleanOne.isPresent()) {
            return ANY;
        }

        Boolean booleanOne = maybeBooleanOne.get();

        if (booleanOne) {
            return "TRUE";
        }

        return ANY;
    }
}
```

The only issue with doing this is that you lose type information in the actual map key (as it's a `List<String>` under the hood). For that reason, I have made the value the equivalent of `Pair<Key, Message>`, in case I need to get to the underlying data in the actual key.

Rationale here is that your type `Key` really (or: probably!) should check its actual field values for equality - and not *derived* values.

So you eventually have a `Map` that looks like this: `Map<StringListMapKey, Pair<Key, Message>>`.

It's not big and it's not clever, but it has served me well and is generic enough to use for other complex criteria that you might want to cache and do quick lookups on.

If performance becomes a consideration (that's a lot of hashing/equals'ing), you can consider a "DelimitiedStringMapKey" that turns your `Key` instance into a plain old String like "foo1:bar1:$ANY:$ANY".

Comment: This is good, but I would still prefer to not have a string representation. The string representation could break in future and having this sort of collection ```Map<StringListMapKey, Pair<Key, Message>>``` seems hard to maintain.

Comment: Agree, it is a little clumsy. For the record, a coworker solved this by implementing a "MapKeyType"  that encapsulated the original "Key" instance -- and had a number of supplemental integer fields that tied to the enum ordinal (in the case of positive integers) or specific well-known values (in the case of negative integers). Then his equals/hashcode methods checked the "mandatory" fields for equivalence/hash and used the integer fields for the specialization. Then it was simply Map<MapKeyType, Message>. Folks preferred that solution. *Edit: this was for a high-volume in-node in-memory cache.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use 'Chain of responsibility design pattern'. You can think of creating a Key criteria to be a node in the chain. Each node has its way of evaluating a given criteria.

https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility

Comment: This is a good idea, but am looking for something more light-weight, similar to list, map or their transformed variants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams to match a key (alias configuration) against a key from your map (alias rules). Here is is what I executed:

```java
    class Matcher {
        Map<Key, Value> rules;
        Matcher(Map<Key, Value> rules)
        {
            this.rules = rules;
        }
        public Optional<Message> findMessage(Key configuration)
        {
            return rules.keySet().stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.required_enum_one == configuration.required_enum_one)
                    .filter(e -> e.required_enum_two == configuration.required_enum_two)
                    .filter(e -> ! e.optional_boolean_one.isPresent() || e.optional_boolean_one.equals(configuration.optional_boolean_one))
                    .filter(e -> ! e.optional_enum_two.isPresent() || e.optional_enum_two.equals(configuration.optional_enum_two))
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(e -> rules.get(e).message);
         }
    }

    // Test
    Matcher matcher = new Matcher(rules);
    Key configuration1 = new Key(foo1, bar1, Optional.of(true), Optional.of(baz1));
    System.out.println("configuration1: " + matcher.findMessage(configuration1));
    Key configuration2 = new Key(foo1, bar1, Optional.of(true), Optional.of(baz2));
    System.out.println("configuration2: " + matcher.findMessage(configuration2));
    Key configuration3 = new Key(foo1, bar2, Optional.of(false), Optional.of(baz2));
    System.out.println("configuration3: " + matcher.findMessage(configuration3));
    Key configuration4 = new Key(foo2, bar2, Optional.of(true), Optional.of(baz1));
    System.out.println("configuration4: " + matcher.findMessage(configuration4));
    Key configuration5 = new Key(foo2, bar1, Optional.of(true), Optional.of(baz1));
    System.out.println("configuration5: " + matcher.findMessage(configuration5));
```

The output is:

```
configuration1: Optional[Message=msg1]
configuration2: Optional[Message=msg2]
configuration3: Optional[Message=msg3]
configuration4: Optional[Message=msg4]
configuration5: Optional.empty
```

Here is the boilerplate code with all the class definitions and object initializations to get the sample running:

```
class EnumBar {
}

class EnumFoo {
}

class EnumBaz {
}

class Message {
    String text;
    Message(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Message=" + text;
    }
}

class Key {
    EnumFoo required_enum_one;
    EnumBar required_enum_two;
    Optional<Boolean> optional_boolean_one;
    Optional<EnumBaz> optional_enum_two;
    Key(EnumFoo required_enum_one, EnumBar required_enum_two,
          Optional<Boolean> optional_boolean_one, Optional<EnumBaz> optional_enum_two) {
       this.required_enum_one = required_enum_one;
       this.required_enum_two = required_enum_two;
       this.optional_boolean_one = optional_boolean_one;
       this.optional_enum_two = optional_enum_two;
    }
}

class Value {
    Message message;
    Value(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

EnumBar bar1 = new EnumBar();
EnumBar bar2 = new EnumBar();
EnumFoo foo1 = new EnumFoo();
EnumFoo foo2 = new EnumFoo();
EnumBaz baz1 = new EnumBaz();
EnumBaz baz2 = new EnumBaz();

Message msg1 = new Message("msg1");
Message msg2 = new Message("msg2");
Message msg3 = new Message("msg3");
Message msg4 = new Message("msg4");

Optional<Boolean> anyBooleanValue = Optional.empty();
Optional<EnumBaz> anyBazValue = Optional.empty();

final Map<Key, Value> rules = new HashMap<>();
rules.put(new Key(foo1, bar1, Optional.of(true), Optional.of(baz1)), new Value(msg1));
rules.put(new Key(foo1, bar1, Optional.of(true), anyBazValue), new Value(msg2));
rules.put(new Key(foo1, bar2, anyBooleanValue, anyBazValue), new Value(msg3));
rules.put(new Key(foo2, bar2, anyBooleanValue, anyBazValue), new Value(msg4));
```

There is only one drawback: a map is an unordered list of entries, so if you take the keySet and stream through it, the second rule could be evaluated before the first rule. (That means in our example configuration1 could output message 2). It is just a timing issue with streams and an implementation issue with sets.
You could fix that by using an ordered list instead of a map, but then you cannot evaluate all rules in parallel to save performance (That means using ".parallelStream()" instead of ".stream()"). I have a better idea: just append a priority-field to your rules (Key-Class). Then instead of applying ".first()", use ".max(...)" regarding the priority.